# Quasi Unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Compare the Conjugate transpose $A^*$ of a complex matrix $A_{N X N}$  with the inverse $A^{-1}$. Their elements match, except for the fact that the off-diagonal elements of $A^{-1}$ are opposite to those of $Ah$. 
$AbsDet[A] =1$.  How can I make $A$ unitary?

Comment: Please go through [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) to learn how to format question and It is a good practice to browse through the FAQ when you join.

Comment: Have you tried something?